# Repalce All http to https of page

Tags: jquery

I want to replace all http to https of a page using jquery.

I am trying this :

```
jQuery('a').each(function() {
    var href = jQuery(this).attr('href');
    if (href.indexOf('http:') > -1) {
        href = href.replace('http:', 'https:');
        jQuery(this).attr('href', href);
    }
});
```

**I want to replace http: to https: on page load**
Guide me how to do this?

Comment: I dont see any error. What do you mean not working?Console errors?

Comment: Did you put the code in a `$(document).ready()` function?

Comment: Its not replacing http to https

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could set `protocol` property:

```
$("a[href]").each(function(){
    if( this.protocol === "http:")
        this.protocol = "https:"
});
```

Comment: anyone help me with below please ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59503217/redirect-http-url-to-https-url-using-htaccess

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery's `attr` will not get you the full URL, but what is entered as the href value, which may only be a local path.  Try this instead...

```
jQuery('a').each(function() {
    this.href = this.href.replace("http:", "https:");
});
```

Using `this.href` will get you an absolute URL instead, so it will always be prefixed with the protocol type.