# Redirect http url to https url using htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I using below code in the htaccess file to redirect www to non www domain and the requirement as below.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/example\.com\/" [R=301,L]


RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/example\.com\/" [R=301,L]
```

**Requirements**:

1. **WWW to Non WWW**

   - http://www.example.com to https://example.com
   - https://www.example.com to https://example.com
2. **Non https url to https Url**

   - http://example.com to https://example.com
3. **Any other page non http url to https url**

   - http://example.com/blog/7-best-places-to-visit to https://example.com/blog/7-best-places-to-visit

**Result:**

1. is working fine as expected.
2. & 3 is not working and remains http url when user directly enter in browser. It should upgrade to https url.

Code is running in godaddy shared hosting. Any help will be much appreciated. Please feel free to let me know if any questions.

Answer (score 0):

I use this:

```
RewriteEngine On
# the following line is only needed, if HTTP and HTTPS share the same config
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^/.well-known/
RewriteRule .* https://wiimmfi.de$0 [R=301,L]
```

I excluded `/.well-known/` to update the let's encrypt certificates.

Inside a `<directory>` or for .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^.well-known/
RewriteRule .* https://wiimmfi.de/$0 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: What is .well-known here ? Will it pass for all 3 conditions ?

Comment: As told in my answer: Standard directory for let's encrypt to update certificates.

Comment: I added a HTTPS check for the case, that HTTP and HTTPS shares the same config. This is usual for .htaccess.

Comment: If we can add OR condition in my abobe 301 redirect from all http to https it should work right without even modifying code. Can you please help on my htaccess code itself ?

Comment: I have also used below but doesn't seems like satisfying all my requirements above:    
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
    
    
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]